# Linux low level driver - how to receive multiple commands for a device

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, scsi

I had written a linux scsi low level driver for cdrom. Am able to receive commands one by one from application and am testing it using sg3-utils.

Now I want to receive more than one command while serving the first one.?
for this I tried changing the struct scsi_host members can_queue and cmd_per_lun to some big values like 40, even though not able to receive multiple commands.

Is there any way to test multiple command reception in existing drivers like scsi_debug ?

Answer (score 0):

Please give a little more information ... when you say "receive commands" that implies you are a target. Maybe you mean "sending commands".

Comment: Yes you are right am a scsi target. I want to receive more than one command. Currently am able to receive commands one by one I.e. after serving the first command, am able to receive the second command. My requirement is to receive multiple commands while serving the previous one. Is this really possible?. My actual problem is how to support GET EVENT STATUS NOTIFICATION COMMAMD with immed bit not set. For this if immed bit is not set then I should not reply immediately, if I didnot respond immediately the next commamd is not coming to driver and time out happens.